# Raising 10 to the power of a negative number using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am only interested in n < 0 case,  if n == -3 then I get, 0.001 as desired.
but I reached here through trial and error. Can someone explain to me 'WHY' this works (for n < 0 case only)?

```
public static double power10(int n) {
  if(n == 0){
    return 1;
  }
  else if (n > 10){
    return 10 * power10(n - 1);
  }
  else {
    return 1.0 / power10(-n);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `else if (n > 0)`?

Comment: If `n == 3` this code is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

The Following Function works for both negative and positive powers.

```
double Power(int n1,int n2) {
    if(n2>=0) {
        if(n2==1) {
            return n1; 
        }
        if(n2==0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else { 
            return n1*Power(n1,n2-1);
        }
    }
    else {
        if(n2==-1) {
            return 1.0/n1; 
        }
        else {
            return 1.0/(n1*Power(n1,(-1)*(n2+1)));
        }
    }
```

It will create following recursion tree for Negative example,

[This link will redirect you to the recursion tree to better understanding, How this function will work recursively.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIjCU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your code doesn't work for either 3 or -3. A stack overflow occurs in both cases. I don't know how you got 0.003.

The error in your code is this:

```
else if (n > 10){
```

It should be `n > 0`. instead.

This recursive algorithm should be quite clear if we turn it into a sentence starting with "the nth power of 10 is...":

> The nth power of 10 is:
>
> If n is 0, 1
>
> If n is positive, 10 * (n-1)th power of 10
>
> If n is negative, 1 / -nth power of 10

You can see that all values of n are covered, whether it be 0, positive or negative. In your incorrect code, you treat cases where `0 < n < 10` as "negative numbers". When you negate those and recurse, you get a real negative number, it goes into the `else` again and they are negated again. But they are still not larger than 10, causing infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code here probably give out stack overflow error. 
Try

```
else if(n>0)
```

Now under the above condition function return n th value of 10 and return 1000 (when n is 3 case), Giving you the answer 0.001.