# How to recursively calculate a number raised to a power?

Tags: java

I have tried:

```
static public void power(int n, int X) {

        System.out.print( + " ");

        if (n>0) {
            power(n-1, X);
        }
    }
```

This does not yield a value as I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public int calculatePower(int base, int powerRaised)
{
    if (powerRaised != 0)
        return (base*calculatePower(base, powerRaised-1));
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
static int power(int x, int y) 
{ 
    // Initialize result 
    int temp; 
    if( y == 0) // Base condition
        return 1; 
    temp = power(x, y/2); // recursive calling
    if (y%2 == 0) //checking whether y is even or not
        return temp*temp; 
    else
        return x*temp*temp;  
}
```

Well others have written solution which gives you correct answer but their time complexity is O(n) as you are decreasing the power only by 1. Below solution will take less time O(log n). The trick here is that

```
x^y = x^(y/2) * x^(y/2)
```

so we only need to calculate x^(y/2) and then square it. Now if y is even then there is not problem but when y is odd we have to multiply it with x. For example

3^5 = 3^(5/2) * 3^(5/2)
but (5/2) = 2 so above equation will become 3^2 * 3^2, so we have to multiply it with 3 again then it will become 3 * 3^(5/2) * 3^(5/2)
then 3^2 will be calculated as 3^(2/1) * (3^2/1) here it no need to multiply it with 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static double pow(int a, int pow) {
    if (pow == 0)
        return 1;
    if (pow == 1)
        return a;
    if (pow == -1)
        return 1. / a;
    if (pow > 1)
        return a * pow(a, pow - 1);
    return 1. / (a * pow(a, -1 * (pow + 1)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public long powerfun(int n,int power,long value){
        if(power<1){
            return value;
        }
        else{
            value = value * n;
            return powerfun(n,power-1,value);
        }
    }

     public static void main(String []args){
         HelloWorld hello = new HelloWorld();
        System.out.println(hello.powerfun(5,4,1));
     }
}
```

Comment: keep in mind that this won't work with negative powers, you need to use this code for that -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421850/raising-10-to-the-power-of-a-negative-number-using-recursion/49423079#49423079

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to add comments to explain the logic to you.

```
//Creating a new class
public class RecursivePower {
    
    // Create the function that will calculate the power
    // n is the number to be raised to a power
    // x is the number by which we are raising n
    // i.e. n^x
    public static int power(int n, int x){
        // Anything raised to the 0th power is 1
        // So, check for that
        if (x != 0){
            // Recursively call the power function
            return (n * power(n, x-1));
            
        // If that is true...    
        }else{
            return 1;
        } //end if else
    } //end power

    // Example driver function to show your program is working
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("The number 5 raised to 6 is " + power(5,6));
        System.out.println("The number 10 raised to 3 is " + power(10,3));
    } //end psvm
    
} //end RecursivePower
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering X as number and n as power and if both are positive integers

```
    public static int power(int n, int X) {

            if (n == 0) {
                return 1;
            } else if(n == 1) {
                return X;
            } else {
                return X * power(n-1, X);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's re-write your function:

```
static public void power(int n, int X) {

    System.out.print( + " ");

    if (n>0) {
        power(n-1, X);
    }
}
```

First of all, lets change `void` to `int`.

Afterthat, when `n` equals to 1, we return the result as `X`, because `X^1 = X`:

```
static public int power(int n, int X) {

    if (n>1) {
        return X * power(n-1, X);
    }
    return X;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.println("Enter n");
        int n = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter x");
        int x =s.nextInt();
        if (n>0){
            double pow =Math.pow(n,x);
            System.out.println(pow);
        }
```

Comment: I think the OP didn't intended to use inbuilt pow function. Second your code is syntactically wrong. It won't compile. Third even if you correct the syntax. It is giving wrong o/p. Please correct it.

Comment: What o/p it is giving on i/p n = 5 and x = 3? Your code is giving 64.

Comment: I have edited your code and now it is correct. Please see it.

Comment: Oh ! the problem is n-1
Thanks a lot

Comment: Yup I mean your original code was https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/qvQdnJR6tE. There is curly brace missing in line 6. and yes the n-1 was giving wrong answer. You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

While others have given you solutions in terms of code, I would like to focus on why your code didn't work.

Recursion is a programming technique in which a method (function) calls itself. All recursions possess two certain characteristics:

1. When it calls itself, it does so to solve a smaller problem. In your example, to raise `X` to the power `N`, the method recursively calls itself with the arguments `X` and `N-1`, i.e. solves a smaller problem on each further step.
2. There's eventually a version of the problem which is trivial, such that the recursion can solve it without calling itself and return. This is called base case.

If you are familiar with mathematical induction, recursion is its programming equivalent.

Number two above is what your code is lacking. Your method never returns any number. In the case of raising a number to a power, the base case would be to solve the problem for the number `0` as raising zero to any power yields one, so the code does not need to call itself again to solve this.

So, as others have already suggested, you need two corrections to your code:

1. Add a return type for the method.
2. State the base case explicitly.